# create database when sql server container is started

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have running sql server container

The idea is create custom database , when sql server container is started

Could create database when the container is started ?

Anyone could help me?

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/347#issuecomment-463103108

Comment: thanks ; it's work